Lanczos algorithm for two-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes \mathcal{H}_2$
Consider the Hamiltonian $H_1$ (Hermitian matrix) along with initial state $|\psi_1\rangle$ which can be used to generate the vectors
$$\mathcal{K}_1  = \{H^n_1|\psi_1\rangle : n=0,1,2,\ldots \}$$
The Lanczos algorithm is used to orthonormalize this to get the basis $\{|K^{(1)}_n\rangle: n = 0,1,2,\ldots \}\,.$ Now, consider the Hamiltonian associated with system $A$ and $B$ that are non-interaction so that $H = H_1\otimes I + I\otimes H_2$ along with initial state $|\psi_{12}\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle$ which can be used to generate the vectors
$$\mathcal{K}_{12} = \{H^n|\psi_{12}\rangle : n=0,1,2,\ldots \}$$
The Lanczos algorithm is, therefore, can be used orthonormalized to get the basis $\{|K^{(12)}_n \rangle : n = 0,1,2,\ldots\}\,.$ Since the system is non-interacting, Is it true that
$$\{|K^{(12)}_n\rangle\} = \{|K_p^{(1)}\rangle \otimes |K^{(2)}_q\rangle \} \qquad \text{for some }n,p,q  $$
If not, Is it possible to modify the vector set $\mathcal{K}^{(12)}_n$ to make it such?

It's true that the set $\{|K_p^{(1)}\rangle \otimes |K^{(2)}_q\rangle \}$ is basis, but I'm unsure if it could be generated with lanczos sequence?
